# if else in where clause on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I need a query but I have a criteria depends on situation. As an example :

Lets have a table named table1 that has column named column1 and
                        table2 that has column named column2

In the query in where clause, I need to join this table1 with table2 by column1 and column2 columns. But, I need to do like

```
if 
     column1 = 'x' then my criteria must be column1 = column2
else
     column1 != 'x'
```

How I can write this where clause in Oracle?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: What should happen if column1 is NULL?

Comment: This can't be null because of design.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `OR` condition like this one:

```
WHERE (Column1 <> 'x' OR column1 = column2)
```

(This is normal SQL syntax. Don't know if there is any change in syntax of Oracle. But you can try this logic)

**EDIT:** [(From OP's comment in my answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615531/if-else-in-where-clause-on-oracle/12615546#comment17008516_12615546)

You can do that something like this one:

```
WHERE (column2 != (Select col from table3) OR column1 = 'x')
```

Or

```
WHERE (column2 != (Select col from table3) OR column1 = (Select col from table3))
```

Comment: But there is a point. 'x' comes from an inner SQL query. And in this time it is confused to use. Actually my situation like this

(Select col from table 3) = 'x' then column1 = 'x' else column2 != 'x'

In this time it gets a little harder for me.

Comment: @user1474111 - In future, please don't waste our time with half a requirement.  Give us all the relevant information in your question from the off.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
WHERE (Column1 != 'x' OR (Column1 = 'x' AND column1 = column2))
```